# Using log4j appenders to a org.slf4j.Logger

Tags: java, logging

I'm using SLF4J 1.7.7 and the log4j 1.7.7 binding.

In a particular instance, I am forced to provide the log4j configurations in the code (so no log4j.properties).

I need to create ConsoleAppender and FileAppender instances and add to the RootLogger's appender list.

I was hoping to use something like the below

```
Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
String logTarget = env.get("WP_LOGTARGET");

if(logTarget != null) {
    if(logTarget .equalsIgnoreCase("file")) {
        FileAppender fa = new FileAppender();

        logger.rootLogger().addAppender(fa);
    } else if(logTarget .equalsIgnoreCase("console")) {
        ConsoleAppender console = new ConsoleAppender(); //create appender

        logger.rootLogger().addAppender(console);

    } else {
        // default to System.out.println

    }
} else {
    // default to System.out.println
}
```

Unfortunately, the below won't work because these Logger instances are in the SLF4j Package.

```
logger.rootLogger().addAppender(fa);

logger.rootLogger().addAppender(console);
```

If I skip the SLF4J Logger classes and go with log4j implementations, ofcourse, it works like a charm.

Any ideas?